# Golangで¥をエスケープしたい

Tags: go, 正規表現

Golangで下記の様に正規表現を使い¥記号をエスケープしましたができません。¥マークを指定すればPlayground上でできますが`\`ではできないのでしょうか。

https://play.golang.org/p/WG5IpwgCN9

Comment: `\(BACKSLASH)` と `¥(YEN SIGN)` は別のコードが割り当てられていますので…。`\ ` は `0x5c`、`¥` は `0xa5`(UTF-8 では `0xc2a5`)になります。`¥` を使いたくないのであれば `regexp.Compile(\`\xa5|,\`)` とする方法もあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。

Answer (score 1):

`\ (BACKSLASH)` と `¥ (YEN SIGN)` には別のコードが割り当てられていますので…。

`\` は `0x5c`、`¥` は `0xa5` (UTF-8 では `0xc2a5`) になります。

`¥` を使いたくないのであれば `` regexp.Compile(`\xa5|,`) `` とする方法もあります。

-- [コメントより](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/20447/golang%E3%81%A7%C2%A5%E3%82%92%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84#comment19193_20447)